# Drop column by unique ID value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, filter

I have a dataframe with an ID column, and 2 other columns named "Legal Employer" and "Legacy Legal Employer" like this:

```
ID  Legal Employer  Legacy Legal Employer
1   Warehouse       Warehouse 4
1   Pool            Warehouse 4
1   Drive           Warehouse 4
2   Warehouse   
2   Drive           Warehouse
3   Warehouse       Drive
3   Pool    
4   Drive           Drive 4
4   Warehouse       Drive 4
```

For each unique ID, I want to keep only 1 row, considering the following:

- If for that ID there is a blank (NaN) on column on "Legacy Legal Employer", keep that row and remove the others
- If for that ID there is no blank (NaN) on column on "Legacy Legal Employer", keep the first record and remove others

This would result in this dataframe:

```
ID  Legal Employer  Legacy Legal Employer
1   Warehouse       Warehouse 4
2   Warehouse   
3   Pool    
4   Drive           Drive 4
```

What is the best way to achive this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

Create a boolean mask to check for null values in `Legacy Legal Employer` then group this mask and use `idxmax` to find the index of max value(i.e. True) per group then use this index to filter the rows. PS: In case there is no null value in column, `idxmax` will automatically select the first row.

```
df.loc[df['Legacy Legal Employer'].isna().groupby(df['ID']).idxmax()]
```

#### Alternative solution

Sort the dataframe by the occurrence of null values in `Legacy Legal Employer` then drop the duplicates by `ID` and optionally sort the dataframe by `ID`

```
m = df['Legacy Legal Employer'].isna()
df.iloc[np.argsort(~m)].drop_duplicates('ID').sort_values('ID')
```

#### Result

```
   ID Legal Employer Legacy Legal Employer
0   1      Warehouse           Warehouse 4
3   2      Warehouse                  None
6   3           Pool                  None
7   4          Drive               Drive 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)
 .apply(lambda g:  g.loc[g['Legacy Legal Employer'].isna()]
        if g['Legacy Legal Employer'].isna().any() else g.head(1)))
```

Output:

```
   ID Legal Employer Legacy Legal Employer
0   1      Warehouse           Warehouse 4
3   2      Warehouse                   NaN
6   3           Pool                   NaN
7   4          Drive               Drive 4
```